# is it possible to write a single line of code that will sort list A, but not it's shallow copy list B

Tags: python, list, sorting

is it possible, given these commands, to write a single line of code that will sort mylistA, but not mylistB

```
mylistA = [5,23,7,-1]
mylistB = mylistA
```

Comment: No, because the two names refer to the *same list object*. Assignment does not create copies, shallow or otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a new list -- But the builtin `sorted` always makes a new list, so ...

```
mylistA = [5,23,7,-1]
mylistB = mylistA
mylistA = sorted(mylistA)
```

---

I suppose that I should probably also point out that we can do this very nicely in 2(!) lines:

```
mylistB = [5,23,7,-1]
mylistA = sorted(mylistB)
```

Yeah!

Answer (score 2):

B is not a shallow copy, it is a second variable pointing to the same list - so if you sort it "in-place" you will modify the value pointed by both variables. To make a real shallow copy use slicing or the list constructor:

```
a = [5,23,7,-1]
b = a[:]    # or list(a)
```

In python you can think of all variables as "pointers".